# Find the value of $\dfrac{\sin(A)^8}{a^3}+\dfrac{\cos(A)^8}{a^3}$

Tags: trigonometry

The question is:

> We have been given
>   $$\frac{\sin(A)^4}a+\frac{\cos(A)^4}b=\frac1{a+b};$$
>   find $$\frac{\sin(A)^8}{a^3}+\frac{\cos(A)^8}{a^3}.$$

My reaction: "Hmmm, hi there, tough-looking question..."

My approach: I first multiplied each term by $(a+b)$. After that, I squared.

AND, I finally got this after some manipulation:
$$\frac{b\sin(A)^4}a+\frac{a\cos(A)^4}b=2\sin(A)^2\cos(A)^2.$$
(And something squared after that).

I really can't go further, I could really use some help.

Comment: The exponent for the trig function not for the angle

Comment: Its sin^4(A) and cos^4(A)

Comment: @AmerYR can you see the difference between $\sin(x^2)$ and $\sin(x)^2$?

Comment: The answer is $$\frac1{\left(a+b\right)^3}.$$

Comment: Not interested in the answer, interested in the method. That's how maths is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality $\frac{\sin(A)^4}a+\frac{\cos(A)^4}b=\frac1{a+b}$ is not an identity, of course, but a restriction on the values of $A$. Put $\sin(A)=X$ and $\cos(A)=Y$.

You have the system $$bX^4+aY^4=\frac{ab}{a+b}\\X^2+Y^2=1$$ from which you get
$$X^2=\frac{a}{a+b}\\Y^2=\frac{b}{a+b}$$ Hence, if you have made a typo, in the second denominator, you get
$$\frac{X^8}{a^3}+\frac{Y^8}{b^3}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{(a+b)^3}}$$  (and if you have not made a typo you get another clear solution).

Answer (score 3):

$$(a+b)(bsin^4A +acos^4A) - ab =0 $$
$$ab(1-2sin^2Acos^2A-1 ) +a^2cos^4A +b^2sin^4A =0 $$
$$(acos^2A-bsin^2A)^2 =0$$
$$\frac{cos^2A}{b} =\frac{sin^2A}{a}=\frac{1}{a+b}$$
$$\frac{sin^8A}{a^3}+\frac{cos^8A}{b^3}=\frac{1}{a^3}\frac{a^4}{(a+b)^4} +\frac{1}{b^3}\frac{b^4}{(a+b)^4}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(a+b)^3}$$